# "Proof of foreign residence" for BritRail?

Tags: trains, uk, residency

What kind of "proof of foreign residence" is accepted/expected for a BritRail pass, which is only available to non-UK residents?

The conditions for the pass say that I have to provide such a proof when validating the pass, and whenever challenged to do so by a ticket inspector. I'm somewhat at a loss as to what it is they expect to see. I'll be carrying my (Danish) passport, of course, but supposedly they're looking for *residence* rather than *nationality*.

Various places on the net suggest a driver's license, but I don't have one.

The best I can think of is my Danish health insurance card ("sygesikringskort"). At some level, the fact that the Danish government extends tourist health insurance to me is arguably *evidence* that they consider me resident here ... but most of the text on the card is in Danish, and I doubt a random UK railway employee would even know what it is.

Comment: good luck getting anyone to so much as look at your pass, much less demand supplementary id. I might have shown my Canadian passport when I first got the pass validated. After that simply saying I had the pass usually sufficed, occasionally I got it out but once they saw the cover that was that. I think twice a conductor actually looked at the tickets themselves. I wouldn't worry about this one overmuch.

Comment: @Kate: I had plenty of ticket gate attendants look at the pass. In several cases I had to explain to them what it was -- fortunately I must have looked trustworthy because they believed me. One of these times were a group of Revenue Protection Inspectors who thought I must be a railway employee to have the pass -- but they let me through eventually ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I asked using the contact form on www.britrail.net and got this reply:

> Dear Henning,
>
> We understand your point however your Danish passport is sufficient ID to validate your Britrail pass.
>
> Please don't worry and have a great trip!

I think I'll be bringing a printout of that email ...

Comment: ... and now I'm back home and not a single person asked for proof-of-residence at all. Not even at validating it.